# structure streaming demo,program exit at once like a batch job,not continious,,spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I write a demo for spark structure streaming,source and sink are all just for testing in local mode

```
   val spark=SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
   val stream=spark.readStream.format("rate").option("rowsPerSecond",2).option("rampUpTime",60).load()
   stream.writeStream.format("memory").queryName("rate2").start()
   spark.sql("select * from rate2").show  
   spark.stop
```

When I run it,I just see this output in the console,and the whole jvm terminated after it immediately.

```
+---------+-----+
|timestamp|value|
+---------+-----+
+---------+-----+
```

Since streaming is continuous,I think it should print records second by second,the program should not stop or exit,but if it does not stop,how can the query code be executed?we should use multi-thread or multi-progress?

But even I just execute the start method on the dataframe,it will not hung there.

### So what is the correct way to start a stream process continuously,and then query it later and further later?

follow the answer of mike,i improve the code:

```
   val spark=SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
   spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("error")
   val stream=spark.readStream.format("rate").option("rowsPerSecond",1).option("rampUpTime",1).load()
   val query=stream.writeStream.format("memory").queryName("rate2").start()   
   spark.sql("select 1,* from rate2").show //empty table shown
   Thread.sleep(1000)
   spark.sql("select 2,* from rate2").show //empty table shown
   Thread.sleep(5000)
   spark.sql("select 3,* from rate2").show //some rows shown
   query.awaitTermination(180000)
//   spark.sql("select * from rate2").show  //no where to execute,not reachable
//   spark.stop
```

console format is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JVM (SparkSession) is terminating because you are calling `spark.stop`.

Instead of stopping your SparkSession you should rather wait for a termination signal (could be Ctrl+C or SIGTERM) through

```
stream.awaitTermination()
```

See example in [Spark Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#quick-example).

Comment: I improved the code in the question,now program hung there,but no result printed in the console,I think it is because the `show` is not reachable,if I create a new spark session,does the query still work?or I launch a  new thread?

Comment: I try to launch a thread before the `awaitTermination`,indeed it print result.but is this the standard way to use stream,or things is different when use master as yarn,then can we share the spark session between two spark shell?

Comment: Try changing the order of the lines. query.awaitTermination should be the very last one. Have you tried printing the results directly to the console with `format.("console")`?

Comment: No need to have multiple SparkSessions... just take care of the order. And yes, this is the usual usage of streams even when submitting them to YARN or other resource managers.

Comment: console format is perfect,code improved again,but I just feel the memory format is strange,I must define in advance when to view results, not anytime